# How do I get the webcam on a Dell Inspiron 14N 4050 working?

Tags: webcam

I am using Dell Inspiron 14 N 4050 which is equipd with a HD video webcam. The webcam is not detected nether working by OS e.e. Ubuntu 10. Please any body help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct program to find and use the webcam.

Here is an answer to a similar question about a external webcam, but the answer is the same.  Answer by Luis Alvarado.

[Can I install an external webcam successfully](https://askubuntu.com/a/152349/65969)